# Virtual host not working in tomcat6

Tags: linux, tomcat6, virtualhost

I am using Linux 12.04 Precise. I just have sudo rights on my machine. I have created a jsp website and tried to create virtual hosts on my machine so that the website url look distinguished like :

```
www.myapp.com
```

rather than

```
127.0.0.1/myapp/
```

So, after going through many articles on the internet. Like

[Virtual-hosting-how-to](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html)

I have created an entry in server.xml like below for my virtual host

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
</Host>
<Host name="www.myapp.com" appBase="libapps" unpackWARs="true"
        autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
</Host>
</Engine>
```

For this, as mentioned in the tutorial, I have created a directory in $CATALINA_HOME named libapps and placed my application war file inside. When i look into the host-manager app of tomcat6, it is showing my virtual host but it is not working on starting. Before this, i have restarted tomcat6 on changing server.xml.

What else can i do to make my application functional ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done with simple steps after a long follow through of internet tutorials :)

Step 1 : Add an entry in your server.xml

```
<Host name="www.your-domain.com"  appBase="libapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
</Host>
```

Step 2 : Create directories in your $CATALINA_HOME for the appbase

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/tomcat6/libapps
```

Create following directories for virtual-host configuration

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/tomcat6/conf/Catalina/www.your-domain.com
```

Copy following files to this directory

```
host-manager.xml
manager.xml
ROOT.xml
```

from

```
/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/Catalina/localhost
```

directory

Step 3 : Add an entry in /etc/hosts file

```
XX.XX.XX.XX     www.your-domain.com
```

Step 4 : After this just restart your tomcat using following command

```
sudo service tomcat6 restart
```

Step 5 : Now, you can access your new virtual-host by typing following url in your browser

```
www.your-domain.com:8080
```

Step 6 : Just access manager app from this host and deploy your war file. :)

Step 7 : Now, if you want to remove ip address from the url and use a good looking url like

```
www.your-domain.com
```

Then, you have to make an entry in

```
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

like below:

```
ProxyPass / http://www.your-domain.com:8080/app-name/
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.your-domain.com:8080/app-name/
```

Step 8 : Now, you can access your application from

```
www.your-domain.com
```

Comment: The ROOT.xml file is missing in my localhost folder. Infact that file is not there in any of my folders in the Catalina folder. Any solutions how can I add my domain as a virtual host?

Comment: ROOT.xml is just a context file for the ROOT web application, in order to host your website, just use the host-manager